# Circular increment: Which is "better"?

Tags: java, coding-style

When you have a circular buffer represented as an array, and you need the index to wraparound (i.e., when you reach the highest possible index and increment it), is it "better" to:

```
return (++i == buffer.length) ? 0: i;
```

Or

```
return ++i % buffer.length;
```

Has using the modulo operator any drawbacks? Is it less readable than the first solution?

**EDIT:**

Of course it should be ++i instead of i++, changed that.

**EDIT 2:**

One interesting note: I found the first line of code in ArrayBlockingQueue's implementation by Doug Lea.

Comment: A subjective question like this one can only bring "both are good" replies.

Comment: @Riduidel: Or "both are bad".

Comment: I personally like the second best because I love the % operator :-).

Comment: does bufer.length ever get changed independantly of i?

Comment: Is there any drawback of using clear code, e.g. i++; if (i == buffer.length) { return 0; } else { return i;} ? Much more easily understood which is nice when you check some code quickly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Update*: OP has admitted in a comment that it **should** have been pre-increment instead. Most of the other answers missed this. There lies proof that the increment in this scenario leads to horrible readability: there's a bug, and most people couldn't see it.

The most readable version is the following:

```
return (i == buffer.length-1) ? 0 : i+1;
```

Using `++` adds unnecessary side effect to the check (not to mention that I strongly feel that you should've used pre-increment instead)

What's the problem with the original code? Let's have a look, shall we?

```
return (i++ == N) ? 0 : i; // OP's original, slightly rewritten
```

So we know that:

- `i` is **post**-incremented, so when `i == N-1` before the `return` statement, this will return `N` instead of wrapping to 0 immediately

  - Is this intended? Most of the time, the intent is to use `N` as an **exclusive** upper bound
- The variable name `i` suggests a local variable by naming convention, but is it really?

  - Need to double check if it's a field, due to side-effect

In comparison:

```
return (i == N-1) ? 0 : i+1; // proposed alternative
```

Here we know that:

- `i` is not modified, doesn't matter if it's local variable or field
- When `i == N-1`, the returned value is `0`, which is more typical scenario

---

#### The `%` approach

Alternatively, you can also use the `%` version as follows:

```
return (i+1) % N;
```

What's the problem with `%`? Well, the problem is that even though most people think it's the *modulo* operator, it's NOT! It's the *remainder* operator ([JLS 15.17.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.17.3)). A lot of people often get this confused. Here's a classic example:

```
boolean isOdd(int n) {
   return (n % 2) == 1; // does this work???
}
```

That code is broken!!! It returns `false` for all negative values! The problem is that `-1 % 2 == -1`, although mathematically `-1 = 1 (mod 2)`.

`%` can be tricky, and that's why I recommend the ternary operator version instead. The most important part, though, is to remove the side-effect of the increment.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia: modulo operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Except if he actually -needs- the side effect of course. This could be one of those times when the side effect is intended, in which case removing it would introduce a new bug. :)

Comment: @Helper: and THAT's why you shouldn't use increment in this case; just use plain `+1` expression, it's a LOT more readable. There's your proof: you made a mistake, and most people couldn't even spot it.

Comment: "there's a bug, and most people couldn't see it." People didn't see the bug, yes, but they _couldn't_ see it either. The original code just had a _different_ meaning. You can't tell that it's a bug without the context.

Comment: @Daniel: Writing in such a way that people couldn't see a bug if there's one is precisely what makes code unreadable. My answer, on the other hand, stands on its own requiring very little context to understand intent and verify correctness.

Comment: @polygenelubricants. I totally agree with your main point; see my answer in the same sense. I just made a minor comment about people "not seeing the bug".

Comment: Another reason you're correct is performance:  '%' and division are about the 2 slowest machine-code instructions that a typical CPU can perform and much slower than an integer comparison + branch.

Comment: I would change `== N` to `>= N` - it is slightly more reliable and error-proof.

Comment: @TimCooper that depends how predictable the branch is. It's almost always meaningless to talk about "performance" in this kind of context.

Answer (score 5):

Don't ask me to choose between two options which both contain postincrement (*) mixed with expression evaluation. I'll say "none".

**(*) Update:** It was later fixed to preincrement.

Comment: Why? Pre- and post-incrementing are frequently used like that, I would expect it to be very readable for many programmers.

Comment: Then surprise: Nobody can read post and pre increment in expressions, and they should never, ever be used like that because it's flat out unnecessary to introduce such bugs for the sake of one extra local variable.

Comment: @Oak The _original poster_ got them wrong. If you use these constructs, you're bound to have some errors and/or misunderstandings. I had to ask myself "is this (postincrement) what he intended, or just a bug?", and how could I tell, without a context? I know the answer just because he edited the question later. What if that code was written by a former coworker, whom I can't ask anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't the `i++ % buffer.length` version have the drawback that it keeps incrementing i, which could lead to it hitting some sort of max_int/max_long/max_whatever limit?

Also, I would split this into

```
i = (i++ == buffer.length) ? 0 : i;
return i;
```

since otherwise you'd most likely have a bug.

Comment: +1: I was just about to point out the overflow problem, too - you were faster. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the condition approach even if we use **unsigned** type, modulo operation has drawbacks.  Using modulo has a bad side effect when the number tested rolls back to zero

Example:

```
255 % 7 == 3
```

So if you use byte (unsigned char) for example, when the number roll after 255 (i.e. zero), it will not result to 4.  Should result to 4 (when 256 % 7), so it rotates correctly.  So just use testing(`if` and `ternary operator`) constructs for correctness

---

If for achieving performance, **and** if the number is multiple of 2 (i.e. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64,  ...), use `&` operator.

So if the buffer length is 16, use:

```
n & 15
```

If buffer length is 64, use 63:

```
n & 63
```

Those rotate correctly even if the number goes back to zero. By the way, if the number is multiple of 2, even the modulo/remainder approach would also fit the bill, i.e. it will rotate correctly.  But I can hazard a guess that `&` operation is faster than `%` operation.

Answer (score 3):

The first one will give you an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because i is never actually reset to 0.

The second one will (probably) give you an overflow error (or related undesirable effect) when i == Integer.MAX_VALUE (which might not actually happen in your case, but isn't good practice, IMHO).

So I'd say the second one is "more correct", but I would use something like:

```
i = (i+1) % buffer.length;
return i;
```

Which I think has neither of the two problems.

I went ahead and tested everyone's code, and was sad to find that only one of the previous posts (at the time of this post's writing) works. (Which one? Try them all to find out! You might be surprised!)

```
public class asdf {

    static int i=0;
    static int[] buffer = {0,1,2};

    public static final void main(String args[]){
        for(int j=0; j<5; j++){
            System.out.println(buffer[getIndex()]);
        }
    }

    public static int getIndex(){
//      return (++i == buffer.length) ? 0: i;
//      return ++i % buffer.length;

//      i = (i++ == buffer.length) ? 0 : i;
//      return i;

//      i++;
//      if (i >= buffer.length) 
//      {
//        i = 0;
//      }
//      return i;

//      return (i+1 == buffer.length) ? 0 : i+1;

        i = (i+1) % buffer.length;
        return i;
    }

}
```

Expected output is:
1
2
0
1
2

Apologies in advance if there's a coding error on my part and I accidentally insult someone! x.x

PS: +1 for the previous comment about not using post-increment with equality checks (I can't actually upmod posts yet =/ )

Comment: Spoiler alert!
Only the uncommented code and the 6-liner work, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

I think the second solution has the clear advantage that it works, whereas the first does not. The first solution will always return zero when `i` becomes bigger than `buffer.length` because `i` is never reset.

The modulo operator has no drawbacks.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it would be more readable to use an if:

```
i++;
if (i >= buffer.length) 
{
  i = 0;
}
return i;
```

Depends a bit if buffer.length ever changes.

Comment: No way. Ternary operator is designed for this kind of case. `if` is terrible choice here.

Comment: @polygenelubricants: Ternary operator should be banned. :-) This is most readable version so far.

Comment: I think the ternary operator fits perfectly here, the real problem is that it's not as readable as it could be. If the "if" would be an expression (like in JavaFX), it would look like if(i >= buffer.length) 0 else i

Comment: @Helper: I'm with you. Use `if` when branching is at statement level (do this or do that). When branching is at expression level (do the following with this value or that value), use ternary.

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective and depends on what your colleagues are used to see. I would personally prefer the first option, as it expresses explicitly what the code does, i.e. if the buffer length is reached, reset to 0. You don't have to perform any mathematical thinking or even know what the modulo does (of course you should! :)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer the modulo approach. When I see modulo, I immediately think of range limiting and looping but when I see the ternary operator, I always want to think more carefully about it simply because there are more terms to look at. Readability is subjective though, as you already pointed out in your tagging, and I suspect that most people will disagree with my opinion.

However, performance is not subjective. Modulo implies a divison operation which is often slower than a comparison against zero. Obviously, this is more difficult to determine in Java since we're not compiling to native code until the jitter kicks in.

My advice would be write which ever *you* feel is most appropriate (so long as it works!) and get a colleague (assuming you have one) to asses it. If they disagree, ask another colleague - then go with the majority vote. #codingbydemocracy

Answer (score 1):

It is also worth noting, that if our buffer has length of power of 2 then very efficient bit manipulation will work:

```
idx = (idx + 1) & (length - 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use also bit manipulation:

```
idx = idx & ((idx-length)>>31)
```

But it's not faster than the if-variant on my machine.

Here is some code to compare running time in C#:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
long cnt = 0;
int k = 0;
int modulo = 10;

sw.Start();
k = 0;
cnt = 0;
for ( int j=0 ; j<100000000 ; j++ ) {
    k = (k+1) % modulo;
    cnt += k;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( "modulo cnt=" + cnt.ToString() + "     " + sw.Elapsed.ToString() );
sw.Reset();


sw.Start();
k = 0;
cnt = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) {
    if ( ++k == modulo )
        k = 0;
    cnt += k;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( "if     cnt=" + cnt.ToString() + "     " + sw.Elapsed.ToString() );
sw.Reset();

sw.Start();
k = 0;
cnt = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < 100000000; j++) {
    ++k;
    k = k&((k-modulo)>>31);
    cnt += k;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( "bit    cnt=" + cnt.ToString() + "     " + sw.Elapsed.ToString() );
```

The Output:

```
modulo cnt=450000000     00:00:00.6406035
if     cnt=450000000     00:00:00.2058015
bit    cnt=450000000     00:00:00.2182448
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the modulo operator for the simple reason it is shorter. And any program should be able to dream in modulo since it is almost as common as a plus operator.

Comment: `%` is not the modulo operator; it's the remainder operator (JLS 15.17.3). In Java, `-1 % 2 == -1`. In mathematics, `-1 mod 2 = 1`.